# Implementing macro processing in C

Tags: c, hash, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a program that acts like the standard preprocessor (I don't intend it to be as vast and deal with all limit cases, but in principle). I have already done the `#include` processing, and `#define` without args, but I don't know how to deal with the argument of the `#define`.

The question is about implementing macros with arguments.

So I have this node I built after reading the statement: `#define add(a,b) a+b`

```
struct list
{
   name:          "add"
   defined name:  "a+b"
   next adress:    17204(adress of next node in the list)
}
```

And now I got the call in `main()`:    `add(2,3)`.    So I go into the above node, and somehow the `x+y` should change into `2+3`, as read by the argument. And then past the altered string.

Please give me any suggestion, you can add data to the the node if needed.

Comment: Format your question properly, please, and pass it through automatic spell-checker.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use inline functions instead?  They are as fast as macros, and a lot less error-prone.... https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The first question is why not to use the standard preprocessor. But anyway, the question is about implementing custom preprocessor for some reason, as I understand it.

Comment: all right I will try to edit it better, and as for the macros, I don't intend to use the macros as a function, I want to get a file which allready has macros defined in it, and implement them, as the one who wrote the macros expect them to work

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise? Why not to use the standard preprocessor?

Comment: The code you posted prints what you say it should, but no sign of any code which is not working.

Comment: Now that was a *significant* edit...

Comment: I tried to make it more readable. I am trying to write a program that acts like standart preprocessor (I don't intend it to be as vast and deal with all limit cases, but in principle). I have already done the #include processing, and #define with out args, but I don't know how to deal with the argument of the #define

Comment: Answer for Wether Vane: yes, it works as the preprocessor does it, I want to recieve a 'text' file, and make certain changes on this file, so the file would look as it passed throgh the preprocessor, but in fact it have not been compiled

Comment: Do you make use of a tokenizer?

Comment: The C preprocessor is built around tokenizing its input according to C rules.  If the input that you intend to feed to your macro processor complies with those rules, then you could as easily feed it to the standard preprocessor (without trying to compile it).  If not, then the C preprocessor may not be a good model for your design.

Comment: A basic tip for when asking for help: have in the question a specific example of what you want to happen. For example, "When I do xyzzy, I'd like the following output: "blah blah blah"

Comment: I havn't used a tokenizer, but getting the arguments characters was not the problem.  I can't insert the arguments into the defenition of the 'defined' word.

Comment: Look into existing preprocessors. Did you consider studying [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) source code, or simply using it ?

Comment: Where does `x+y` come from? The definition was `#define add(a,b) a+b`. Was that a typo or are you doing some kind of alpha rewrite?

Comment: Thanks every bodey, I have found a solution to my problem. If your are interested  of knowing the solution I found for some reason, tell me and I woud post it here.